# Get a random member of a container

Tags: c++, random, collections

It was not obvious how to get a random member of a container. So I wrote a function to retrieve it given a generator.

```
namesapce ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Util
    {
        using Distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;

        /* Get a distribution from [0, max)   */
        /* None maths nerds: Note the [ and ) */
        Distribution getDist(int max)
        {
            return Distribution{0, max - 1};
        }

        template<typename C, typename G>
        auto getRandomIteratorFromContainer(C& container, G& generator)
        {
            auto pos = container.begin();

            int     offset  = getDist(container.size())(generator);
            std::advance(pos, offset);

            return pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code not working: `namesapce` Did you test your code? ;)

Comment: It helps reviewers if you show the necessary `#include` lines, rather than us all having to figure out what's required.  And I'd expect `#include <iterator>` in there, as it's impossible to instantiate the template without needing a definition of `std::advance`, even though it can be parsed without.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Long name

`ThorsAnvil::Util::getRandomIteratorFromContainer` is a really long name. I suggest something like `getRandomElement` or even `randomElement`.

#### Unnecessary function

`getDist` seems kind of unnecessary to me. I think it would be cleaner to construct the distribution directly.

```
std::uniform_int_distruction<int> dist{0, container.size() - 1};
```

#### Types

The integer type used for iterator arithmetic is `typename C::difference_type`. This is almost always equivalent to `std::ptrdiff_t` so to be crystal clear, use `std::ptrdiff_t`.

```
std::uniform_int_distruction<std::ptrdiff_t> dist{0, container.size() - 1};
```

#### Unnecessary variable

`offset` is initialized with a random offset and is only used once. If it's only used once then it doesn't really need to exist.

```
std::advance(pos, dist(generator));
```

#### Wrong function

`std::advance` modifies an existing iterator. This means that we need store the iterator, advance it, then return the iterator. That's three steps. `std::next` takes an iterator and returns an incremented one.

```
return std::next(container.begin(), dist(generator));
```

#### Covering all cases

Using `.begin()` and `.size()` is a little bit restrictive. If we use `std::begin` and `std::size`, this function will work on C-style arrays which is a nice. If we want to be even more general (as Toby mentioned in the comments), we can let ADL pick up the right function for containers that declare their own `begin` and `size` functions.

```
using std::begin;
using std::size;
```

#### Short names

My answer has been pretty nitpicky so far but this is particularly nitpicky. Long template parameter names that clearly describe the parameter are better than single character names.

```
template <typename Container, typename Generator>
```

#### How I would write it

After applying the above transformations. We get this function:

```
template <typename Container, typename Generator>
auto random_element(Container &con, Generator &gen) {
  using std::begin;
  using std::size;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::ptrdiff_t> dist{0, size(con) - 1};
  return std::next(begin(con), dist(gen));
}
```

Comment: Technically, it should be `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @user673679 They're the same thing. It's *personal preference* whether you use `ptrdiff_t` or `std::ptrdiff_t`. I personally don't see the point in the extra 5 characters.

Comment: Yeah. I'd prefer to use the one that's guaranteed to exist.

Comment: There's one aspect you changed, but didn't mention explicitly, the use of `C` and `G` as names. One thing is that these single letters don't convey much information. Another thing is that these are `ALL_UPPERCASE`, so one could even mistake them for macros.

Comment: @uli I did mention this under **Short names**. I don't think they could be mistaken for macros as it's pretty common to use single character names for template parameters (thanks Java!). Sometimes you can't be more specific than "a type" so you just use `T`.

Comment: That must have escaped me. Sorry, @Kerndog73.

Comment: Thanks. Agree with most of that. Long names!! We have `namespace TU = ThorsAnvil::Util;` to cope with that.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Kerndog73's answer:

- Don't forget to check for an empty container to avoid undefined behavior. We should probably return the `end()` iterator in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of accepting a container, accept an iterator pair.  We may want to use just part of a container (e.g. after using `std::partition`).  In C++20, a standard `forward_range` view could be used.

It probably makes sense to use different implementations for forward-access and random-access collections (there's a single-pass algorithm for selecting 1 out of an unknown number of elements, so we could even accept input iterators).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should clarify what you want. Depending on that, the answer will be slightly different.

If you want an iterator to a random element then Kerndog's answer is really close:

```
template <typename Container, typename Generator>
auto random_iterator(Container &con, Generator &gen) {
  using std::begin;
  using std::size;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::ptrdiff_t> dist{0, size(con) - 1};
  return std::next(begin(con), dist(gen));
}

template <typename Container, typename Generator>
auto random_iterator(const Container &con, Generator &gen) {
  using std::cbegin;
  using std::size;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::ptrdiff_t> dist{0, size(con) - 1};
  return std::next(cbegin(con), dist(gen));
}
```

Note that there should be a const/non-const overload.

If you only want the element from the container you should retrieve it or get a reference?

```
template <typename Container, typename Generator>
auto random_reference(const Container &con, Generator &gen) {
  using std::size;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist{0, size(con) - 1};
  return con[dist(gen)];
}
```

Which standard do you use? If C++20 is possible then you should use at least the `range` concept and `ranges::size`:

```
template <range Container, typename Generator>
auto random_const_iterator(const Container &con, Generator &gen) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::ptrdiff_t> dist{0, std::ranges::size(con) - 1};
  return std::next(std::ranges::cbegin(con), dist(gen));
}
```

Note that `std::ranges::size`/`std::ranges::cbegin` are customization point objects (CPOs), so you should call them qualified; you do not need to use ADL as that is already inside the mechanics of the CPO.

Comment: The `const` overload isn't necessary. If `Container` is `const`, `begin` will return a `const` iterator. `random_reference` won't uses the subscription operator so it will only work on vectors and arrays. `random_reference` should probably call `random_iterator`. I'm really glad that ADL nonsense is hidden away in `std::ranges::*`. That's one "pattern" that I really dislike. I'm guessing `std::swap` still has the same problem though.

Comment: Jeez, I clearly didn't proofread that comment before sending it!

Comment: Don't believe I need different variants for cont and non const versions. The Type C will automatically adapt to both versions correctly. Most containers have two versions of `begin()` a const and a non const version.